# How to set access rights for files uploaded to s3 server using fedemotta Yii2 extension?

Tags: amazon-s3, yii2

I can properly upload files to my s3 bucket using [fedemotta yii2-aws-sdk extension](https://github.com/fedemotta/yii2-aws-sdk). I cannot access the files because I have to set access rights to each file I upload. 
My config looks something like this:

```
'components' => [
        'awssdk' => [
                'class' => 'fedemotta\awssdk\AwsSdk',
                'credentials' => [ 
                        'key' => 'ZXCV',
                        'secret' => 'zxcv',
                ],
                'region' => 'us-east-1',                    
                'version' => 'latest',
        ],
```

I found out that in the default yii2-file-upload extension, it can be done using  `setACL('public-read')`. How do I do this in fedemotta extension?

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/yii2tech/file-storage extension made by one of the Yii 2 core members that handles AWS S3 perfectly?

Comment: Thanks will check it out

Comment: @Bizley I'm trying to implement it...but in the documentation there is no sample config for s3...can you help me out please?

Comment: There is sample in the class: https://github.com/yii2tech/file-storage/blob/master/amazon/Storage.php

Comment: @Bizley sorry to be bugging u but I am unable to find any field that takes in the path of specific folder in the bucket. it only asks for the bucket. How do I specify the path for the folder in the bucket?

Comment: Usually you only specify file name because you should not care exactly where the file is stored. I'm using this bucket option: `'fileSubDirTemplate' => '{ext}/{^name}/{^^name}',` so files are automatically stored in folders based on extension and name i.e. `abc.jpg` will be stored at `jpg/a/b/` - but I call for `abc.jpg` and not worrying about the inside path.

Comment: @Bizley thanks I did just that and using `$bucket->copyFileIn()` i get false as result after var_dump(). what could possibly be the reason..any idea?

Comment: Please create separate question for this and let me know.

Comment: @Bizley yeah i thought of that too..and yeah you can write the earlier suggestion as an answer...its qute helpful. will upvote.. and will post another question relating to this pls respond

Comment: @Bizley posted a question tagged amazon-s3 please help ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Just add `'ACL' => 'public-read',` to your upload function in the model

```
$this->s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'       => $bucket,
            'Key'          => $keyname,
            'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            ));`
```